# Is MySQL 5.7 compatible?

Tags: 7, database

My server has been on MySQL 5.6 for quite awhile and now I need to upgrade to MySQL 5.7. Is it safe to upgrade to 5.7 for all of my Drupal 7.x sites? Just doing a quick google for *drupal 7 mysql 5.7*, I get a few people reporting issues when updating with Drupal 7.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. MySQL 5.7 is compatible with D7.x. Per [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/database-server):

> Drupal 7 supports MySQL 5.0.15/MySQL 5.1.30/MariaDB 5.1.44/Percona
>   Server 5.1.70 or higher, and requires the PDO database extension for
>   PHP (see [What is PDO?](https://www.drupal.org/requirements/pdo)).

Is it safe? *Maybe*. It depends on your code/infrastructure setup.

Just because a web application is compatible with a version of a DB server, doesn't mean an upgrade will happen flawlessly. There can be many things that could go wrong (e.g. hidden dependencies).

It will *probably* be fine with a minor version upgrade, but always have a test/backup plan in place when rolling out infrastructure changes.